# Sculptures on the Hindu temples of the Ajanta and Ellora caves

Tags: temple, homosexuality

The [*Ajanta*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajanta_Caves) caves have temples in the range of a *100 kms* which have many *Hindu* temples. (There are *Jain* and *Buddhist* temples too).

The [*Ellora*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellora_Caves#The_Kailasanatha_temple) caves also have a lot of *Hindu* temples, greater in proportion as compared to the *Ajanta* caves.

These *Hindu* temples have sculptures which depict many homosexual acts.

Can these sculptures be taken as an indicator of Hinduism's support towards homosexuality and that 'Hinduism does not see homosexuality as a crime'?

If not, what was the intention of these sculptures on the temples?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Hinduism's view on appropriate societal norms?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/54584/what-is-hinduisms-view-on-appropriate-societal-norms)